# Allegro Crashes When Loading Bitmap

Tags: c++, bitmap, bmp, allegro

I've looked around and their are similar questions but the answers haven't fixed my problem.

So, the problem is - If i try to load/draw bmp's in allegro it crashes, they are in the same directory as my project, they are named correctly, i believe the problem lies within the bmp itself. If i use the bmp's from the tutorial im using they work fine, however if i try to create my own, allegro crashes on startup, is there some sort of preset bmp i can use to create my sprites? I've gone over my code multiple times but if i missed something please point it out :)

My Code:

```
#include <allegro.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// Startup Stuff
allegro_init();
install_keyboard();
set_color_depth(16);
set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT, 640, 480, 0, 0);

// Bitmap Stuff
BITMAP *pic = NULL;

pic = load_bitmap("enemy.bmp", NULL);


blit(pic, screen, 0,0,0,0,200,150);//Draw the whole bitmap to the screen at (0,0)

readkey(); // Wait for Key Press.

destroy_bitmap(pic);



return 0;
}
END_OF_MAIN();
```

[Tutorial Im Reading](http://www.loomsoft.net/resources/alltut/alltut_index.htm)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the stack trace look like?

Comment: @JohnSaxton

Apologies, i forgot to mention i'm quite new, im on devcpp, where can i retrieve the stack trace?

Comment: You should always check the return values and react accordingly. Then your program won't mysteriously crash. `if (!pic) { /* print unable to load bitmap & quit */ }`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the color depth, the bmp's i made were 16 bit, changing them to 24 bit fixed the problem!